Plotting vector field at specific locations
I have two csv files. One that contains the site locations of a lattice and then other that contains the locations corresponding vector data.
I import both data sets as:
Spins = {{-0.378353,0.599086,0.705652},{0.680068,0.116473,0.723838},{-0.358016,0.539119,0.762349},{0.742107,0.0656055,0.667063}}
Sites = {{0.,0.,0.},{-0.204124,-0.353553,0.57735},{-0.408248,-0.707107,1.1547},{-0.612372,-1.06066,1.73205}}

From here I wish to plot the spins at the respective location. My initial attempt was to plot it as follows:
ListVectorPlot3D[Transpose[{Sites, Spins}]]

However, this fails to generate a useful plot.
After googling it, it seams that I could use Graphics3D. However, there must surly be a better way.

You may use MapThread with Arrow:
Spins = {{-0.378353, 0.599086, 0.705652}, {0.680068, 0.116473, 
   0.723838}, {-0.358016, 0.539119, 0.762349}, {0.742107, 0.0656055, 
   0.667063}};
Sites = {{0., 0., 0.}, {-0.204124, -0.353553, 
   0.57735}, {-0.408248, -0.707107, 1.1547}, {-0.612372, -1.06066, 
   1.73205}};

Graphics3D[{MapThread[Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}] &, {Sites, Spins}]}, 
 Axes -> True]


